# Are there other proof for Column rank = row rank using the aspect of "transformation"??

Tags: linear-algebra

In some mathematician's taste, they tend to view a matrix as a linear transformation. Hence, some people proved that $\dim C(A)=\dim R(A)$ is true for any matrix $A$ by means of transpose of linear transformations, where the transpose is defined in terms of linear functional/dual space.

However, if one choose not to prove $\dim C(A)=\dim R(A)$ by means of transformations, one may prove them by actually doing some matrix multiplication or linear systems. Well, I want to ask that, is there a proof of $\dim C(A)=\dim R(A)$ that still using the viewpoint of transformations, but not using transpose transformations?

Comment: `Some` only :o)?

Comment: @Bernard I would like to say most, but I can't make an investigation. :)

Comment: Considering matrices *per se* mostly dates back only to the beginnings of Computer Science, I guess.

Comment: it is a difficult question because you are trying to prove that two subspaces have same dimension, but dimension is a notion from the operator's interpretation of matrices.

Comment: @NombreFalso123 Can you say more about "dimension is a notion from the operator's interpretation of matrices"? I'm very interested at it. But I can't quite get what you said.